# Why TEST = Hello with blanks doesnt work in the terminal?

Tags: command-line

When I wanna define TEST in Terminal like: TEST = Hello, it shows: TEST: Command not found.
Why it woks only like TEST=Hello.
Im asking because all defintions in my makefile are like this and I dont wanna change it.

Answer (score 4):

Makefiles are read and processed by the `make` program, whereas shell scripts are read and processed by a shell interpreter - they have different variable assignment syntax and parsing rules.

There's nothing to say a shell *couldn't* parse assignments with whitespace around the `=` as `make` does - in fact, some shells (notably `csh`) do so, for example

```
#!/bin/csh

set test = hello
echo "$test"
```

however the POSIX `/bin/sh` and Bourne-derived `bash`, as well as `ksh` and `zsh` do not allow it.

Answer (score 2):

In bash a variable assignment has the syntax: `name=[value]`. You cannot put unquoted spaces around the `=` because bash would not interpret this as the assignment you intend. bash treats most lists of words as a command with parameters, e.g. `abc =def # call the command or function 'abc' with '=def' as an argument` <sup>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4977390/)</sup>

Comment: The makefile says:  CC = $(CROSSCOMPILER)gcc , how does it work if the syntax is different

Comment: As the man page for bash builtins states: "Each operator and operand must be a separate argument." however variable assignment is different as described in the answer.