# Variable being parsed as a Command in VI Editor in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash

I am new to Linux and am facing the following issue.
After going into vi mode I enter the following code

```
#!bin/bash

str = "Hello"
echo $str
```

Once back to the main shell, when I execute the file I get the following error

```
Command 'str' not found, but there are 17 similar ones.
```

I am not sure why a variable is being returned as a command. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Why TEST = Hello with blanks doesnt work in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292455/why-test-hello-with-blanks-doesnt-work-in-the-terminal)

Comment: Thankyou ! Got why this was creating issues